# How to Set Email notification for all projects in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to set an email notification for all TFS projects, the thing is I know how to set it up for each project individually but I have a lot of projects so I want a way to set it up for all projects or for a collection at once. Plus I want the notification to be sent for all team project members.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **directly create collection level notifications** for **all** teams/groups/users is ***not supported*** for now.

However if your just want to set a notification for a specific Group/User across an entire collection, then you can try below steps:

1. Create a Group -> Add memebers to the group
2. Navigate to **Notifications** hub in collection level
3. Switch to **Subscribers** tab -> **Search Users and Groups** ->
   Select the specific user/group
4. **New Subscription** -> **Build** -> **A build fails** -> **Next** ->  Deliver to : **Individual xxx members** or **Team email address** ->
   Filter: **Any team project**

Just as *ChamindaC* suggested, to achieve your requirement, you may have to use same 3rd-party extension or create your own to perform the sending notifications action. An [open source project](https://github.com/kria/TfsNotificationRelay) on GitHub about handing email notifications for
your reference:

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting any team project and custom email addresses. But the collection level notification setup is not available out of the box.
[image]

Since there is no out of box way to create notification for all projects at once you may automate this. You can use PowerShell and write a script using TFS REST API so that the script is creating notifications for all the team projects. Notification create API is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/hooks/notifications/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1). You can retrieve all team projects in a collection and loop through them to create the notification you want.

Comment: This is not gonna work for me, because each project has his own team members. And I want the project team members only to receive the email.

Comment: @user3651708 the collection level notification setup is not available as of now. However you may create powershell script to create all notifications you want . For this you can use TFS REST API  . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/hooks/notifications/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1